# passing data from middleware to view or alternative way to show specific data in every page

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

in my website i have a fairly complected category which i have to show in every view (in the client side) so i thought i put the code for creating category in a middleware and pass the result to views

so i've created my middleware but i cant figure out how can i pass its data to my view withouth having to do something in the controllers 
i've tried these methods in my middleware

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class CtegoryMiddleware
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $request->merge(array("all_categories" => "abc"));
        $request['all_categories']= 'abc';
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

route :

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['category' ]], function () {
     Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index');
});
```

but in my view when i echo all_categories i get

```
Undefined variable: all_categories
```

*btw i've checked by echoing something , the middleware gets triggered on the request*

Comment: While the variable `all_categories` is available on your `$request`, perhaps you didn't pass it to your view within your controller?

Comment: @JofryHS as i said i dont want to do anything in my controllers otherwise i would have created a helper class or something instead .... i just want to have specific data available in all my views  (well most of them)

Comment: Perhaps use `View::share()` to share your variables on your view? https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/views#sharing-data-with-all-views

Comment: thanx this is better but there is no routing and i have to load all categories even in the admin section which i dont need .... i call this plan B

Comment: Not entirely sure what 'there is no routing' means, but technically if you call `view()->share()` ***within*** your middleware, it should share the same variable on all subsequent views

Comment: @JofryHS the documentation is bit vague ,  can i load/grab data in my views of choice or its like a globally available in all the views .. let me ask like this :  the queries necessary to make that data will get executed before each and every view or jut the one that show this data ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think in your use case, using a globally available view variable should suffice.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class CtegoryMiddleware
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $request->merge(array("all_categories" => "abc"));
        $request['all_categories']= 'abc';

        /**
         * This variable is available globally on all your views, and sub-views
         */
        view()->share('global_all_categories', 'abc');

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

The variable is loaded once (if you do database query, the query will only execute once), and the variable is then stored in the View factory.